# Find text in range of cells

Tags: excel, if-statement, spreadsheet

I have a number of cells in each column that contain pass or fail. In a separate cell I want "pass" if there is no "fail" in any of the cell range/row. How can I do this? Screenshot below. 
Thanks in advance.

[image: positions]

Comment: check my answer here: [Check if range contains all equal values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23896385/check-if-range-contains-all-equal-values)

Comment: Thanks. I did see that one but Lior's answer seemed to work better with text, not sure how to change yours for that.

Comment: `=IF(COUNTIF(A1:C1,"pass")=3,"all are pass","fail")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=If(or (A1 <> "Fail" , B1 <> "Fail" , C1 <> "fail") , True , False)
```